# How to get local IP address of user connected through request - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have not been able to find any answer to this. I am looking for a way to obtain the local IP address of the user connected to my node server. I found the answer to find a way to get the user's public IP address, and was useful. I also need a way to determine which computer is connected, so the local IP as well through, possibly, something like this:

```
app.post('getip', function(req,res)
{
 var localIP  = req.headers['something or other'];
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using ExpressJS?

Comment: If the user connects through a gateway (such as from a corporate network or a home network via a router), then there is no evidence of the user's local IP address in the request and it wouldn't do you any good anyway since it's' a private IP address that is not reachable and is not unique.  All you can get access to is the public IP address of the gateway that the user connects through.

Comment: unfortunate. The ip address is unique at the time the public IP address is given, which would be useful to me. I am making something that would benefit from knowing which user is which from a common public IP address. at the instance I am getting the public IP, and only then. So a dynamicly assigned local IP address is ok for me in this application.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the IP in NodeJS if you're behind a proxy like nginx.

```
app.post('getip', function(req, res)
{
  var localIP  = req.headers["x-forwarded-for"];
}
```

Comment: I'm using this right now. It gets me the public IP address, not the private IP address.

Comment: Have you tried the [node-ip](https://github.com/indutny/node-ip) npm? It might be useful.